# Как пропускать изображение размера которого мне нужно?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно чтоб загружалась фотография размера 600х800 как сделать проверку или как?

```js
function preview_images() {
  let total_file = document.getElementById("images").files.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < total_file; i++) {
    $('#image_preview').append("<div class='img__wrapper'><img class='img' src='" + URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]) + "'></div>");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Уже отвечали на этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8904008/14142964). Тебе сначала надо создать HTML-элемент, но не вставлять его. Потом с этого элемента ты можешь получить width и height. Если проверку проходит, то уже можно и отобразить на странице.

Comment: а можно как-то сделать с етим вариантом или нет? если нет то я попрошу вас показать лучший пример пожалуста

Comment: Если с таким вариантом, то можешь попробовать повесить на картинку свойство `display: none` сначала. Потом уже с этой картинки получить width/height, и, если все верно, поменять на `display: block`. Увы, с JQuery я не работал практически, так что пример кода привести не могу.

Comment: а можете помочь написать ето на чистом js , буду очень благодарен

Comment: На чистом JS код есть по ссылке, которая указана в ответе.

Comment: Я толком не понимаю как тот код добавить к моему

Comment: Тому прошу помощи у вас